# bash script user prompt for preferred directory

Tags: bash, scripting, prompt

I am attempting my first bash script. I would like to prompt the user to find out where they would like a cloned repo to be saved.

Currently I am assigning it like this.

```
warpToLocation="${HOME}/apps/"
```

Is there some way to do it like this:

```
read -e -p "Enter the path to the file: " -i "${HOME}/apps/" FILEPATH
```

but save the result as `warpToLocation`?

#### EDIT:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "where would you like to install your repos?"

read -p "Enter the path to the file: " temp
warpToLocation="${HOME}/$temp/"

warpInLocations=("git@github.com:cca/toolkit.git" "git@github.com:cca/sms.git" "git@github.com:cca/boogle.git" "git@github.com:cca/cairo.git")



echo "warping in toolkit, sms, boogle and cairo"
for repo in "${warpInLocations[@]}"
do
  warpInDir=$repo
  warpInDir=${warpInDir#*/}
  warpInDir=${warpInDir%.*}
  if [ -d "$warpToLocation"]; then
    echo "somethings in the way.. $warpInDir all ready exists"
  else
    git clone $repo $warpInDir
fi

done
```

What I had done to get that error was add the code you gave me.

The issue with that is that `-e` (which allows you to edit the input with arrows) and `-i` (a preview/optional answer) runs on bash version 4 and higher and I am running version `GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin12)`.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with

```
read -e -p "Enter the path to the file: " -i "${HOME}/apps/" warpToLocation
```

?

Comment: so FILEPATH is a variable. i thought it was a standard.. thanks man sorry its my first time dipping into bash i am scared i destroy my os

Comment: invalid option
read: usage: read [-ers] [-u fd] [-t timeout] [-p prompt] [-a array] [-n nchars] [-d delim] [name ...]
warping in toolkit, sms, boogle and cairo

Comment: I have no idea what you typed in your program, but I'm pretty sure that the command I told you works in bash. If you type _something else_ and get error messages, it's fairly pointless to copy only the error message and hope that others can reconstruct your problem from that.

Comment: that would be the result that bash gave me when i tried `read -e -p "Enter the path to the file: " -i "${HOME}/apps/" warpToLocation`

Comment: Your `read` doesn't have a `-i` option? Are you really using bash? Which version? `bash --version`

Comment: OK, so you'll have to upgrade if you want to use `read` with a default input value.

Answer (score 0):

It is seldom constructive to ask the user interactively for a pathname.  That limits the scripts usability to interactive use and it forces the user to type in (correctly) a possibly long pathname, without being able to use variable names like `$HOME` or `$project_dir` (or whatever variables the user likes to use) and without using `~`.

Instead, take the pathname to the destination directory from the command line, validate that it's a directory, and clone the Git repositories into it if the they do not already exist.

```
#!/bin/sh

destdir=$1

if [ ! -d "$destdir" ]; then
    printf 'No such directory: %s\n' "$destdir" >&2
    exit 1
fi

for repo in toolkit sms boggle cairo
do
    if [ -e "$destdir/$repo" ]; then
        printf 'Name %s already exists for repository %s (skipping)\n' \
            "$destdir/$repo" "$repo" >&2
        continue
    fi

    printf 'Cloning %s\n' "$repo"
    git clone "git@github.com:cca/$repo.git" "$destdir/$repo"
done
```

This script would be used as

```
./script.sh "$HOME/projects/stuff"
```

and could be run without user interaction from e.g. Ansible or Cron.